# How do you reconize voice from web app

Tags: web-applications, audio, voice-recognition

I want something really simple to identify one word ( "UNO !" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is supper late, but you should be looking at sphinx from CMU.  http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/ProgrammersGuide.html#helloworld
I know the documentation is dry but you can get some basic speech recognition going very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Flash, you can use Ribit and Silverlight for the same.
Refer :

http://developer.ribbit.com/blogs/ribbit-brings-programmable-voice-communications-microsoft-silverlight-and-net-platform-develop

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightVoiceVideoChat.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to use Flash.  It will have to take control of their microphone, which, I believe, they will have to authorize the app to do.

Comment: That's only a very smal part of the solution. Once you can record what they are saying, it's very difficult to recognize the 'UNO' word...